# Solr not including fields having empty value in result

Tags: solr, solrj, solr-query-syntax

Indexed data on Solr contains some fields which are having empty values. When I run `q=*:*` it does not include fields having empty values. What parameter do I need to pass while query to get fields having empty values in the result.

EDIT : 
I am indexing data using a csv file, entries in file are as follows :

```
id, dob, name
1,,name1
2,,name2
```

Now when I search for top 10 records I get only two fields. I want to get all fields even if there is no value stored for that.

Answer (score 1):

Field should have `stored="true"`

Cross check in your schema.xml file about `dob` field. it should have stored="true"

```
<field name="dob" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

reindex the documents and query again, it works.

Hope this help

Comment: Its a dynamic field, similar to `<dynamicField name="*_dob"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />`. This is what written over ther.

Comment: nothing difference if its dynamic field. if stored="true" then it will come in result set like `"i_dob":""`.  Did you reindex ?

Comment: The thing is, I can not specify field name in the query, as I don't know the field name at the time of query. Its all automated and there are multiple dynamic fields.

Comment: Ok. you copy *_dob field to text field in schema file using copyfield. like `<copyField source="*_dob" dest="text"/>`. by default solr search in text field which is specified in config file. reindex and try.  this might work .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124985/discussion-between-vinod-and-prometheus).

Answer (score 1):

If an item doesn't have a piece of data, solr doesn't store the field. You should be able to force storage of an empty string by setting the field attributes required="True" default="".

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean empty fields ? are these fields are set as `indexed=true` ? Are you setting empty say spaces as data when you are indexing these fields ? Looks like you are not sending even a template blank data to this variable , that is why its happening . For example if i send data in this format `{"id":"change.me","title":" "}` , where my title field is empty it gets indexed .But if you try to send a data like this , `{"id":"change.me","title":}` , it will send an error across solr .

Comment: yes all fields are `indexes=true`. I am indexing solr core using a csv file and the data would be something like this for field `id, title,name : 1,,abcd`. I am updating the csv format in my question too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a query add `wt=csv` and you can export a well formed CSV file

Specify the fields you require back using `fl=`

Example:
`select?fl=id,foo,bar&indent=on&q=field:value&stored=true&rows=1000&start=0&wt=json`